# Does Excel have an equivalent to the SQL "UNION" statement?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql

I have an SQL query with two SELECT statements and am using a UNION statement between those two to get a unique result. I need to use this query in Excel but I believe Excel does not accept a UNION statement.

What could be used instead of UNION in the query?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example query from a Microsoft KB article using the UNION statement.
Since that I would say: MS Query (Excel build-in tool for SQL querys) is capable to use UNION-Statements.

```
SELECT Color_Table.Join_Field, Color_Table.Color_Field,
   Pattern_Table.Pattern_Field
   FROM {oj `C:\database`.Pattern_Table LEFT OUTER JOIN
   `C:\database`.Color_Table ON Color_Table.Join_Field =
   Pattern_Table.Join_Field}
   UNION
   SELECT Color_Table.Join_Field, Color_Table.Color_Field,
   Pattern_Table.Pattern_Field
   FROM {oj `C:\database`.Color_Table LEFT OUTER JOIN
   `C:\database`.Pattern_Table ON Color_Table.Join_Field =
   Pattern_Table.Join_Field}
   WHERE (Color_Table.Color_Field Is Null)  or(Pattern_Table.Pattern_Field Is Null)
```

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/136699/en-us